# Replacing original variable using parse_number and mutate in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that contains a set of variables that have a mix of numbers and characters, such as "1 - Completely Disagree." I would like to remove the characters and keep only the numbers, but retain the variables within the original dataset under their original name. So, I have a variable called "systematic1" with the value "1 - Completely Disagree. I would like it to become just "1" in numeric form within the original dataset. This what I have:

| systematic1 | systematic2 | systematic3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - Completely Disagree | 7 - Completely Agree | 7 - Completely Disagree |
| 5 - Somewhat Agree | 4 - Neither Agree nor Disagree | 6 - Agree |

This is the desired output:

| systematic1 | systematic2 | systematic3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 7 |
| 5 | 4 | 6 |

I've been able to mostly accomplish this using the following code:

```
data %>%
   select(systematic1:withdrawn) %>% #select range 
   select_if(is.character) %>% #keep only character vars
   mutate_all(~parse_number(.,na=c("Not sure"))) #parse out number, treating "Not sure" as NA
```

But that produces a new dataframe with those transformed variables. I would like to keep the variables in the original dataset, only transformed.

Comment: `select_if` and `mutate_all` have been superseded. You can use `across`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      systematic1:withdrawn & where(is.character), 
      ~ifelse(str_detect(.x, "\\d+"), str_extract(.x, "\\d+"), "Not sure")
      )
    )
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  systematic1 systematic2 systematic3
  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1 1           7           7          
2 5           4           6
```

Comment: Sorry, I included only a snippet, but the variable names are all over the place, from "systematic" to "warm" to "withdrawn", so I can't use "starts_with" to identify them. There are 145 of these variables, in that range from "systematic" (first variable) to "withdrawn" (last variable), with some numeric variables in between that I don't need to transform.

Comment: Do you need to transform every character variable?

Comment: No, there are some in the df that do not need to be transformed. Only the character variables included in that range.

Comment: Updated my answer, but I'm not sure if this will work.